# Edit Custom Admin Page with Page Editor (e.g. Divi)

Tags: wordpress

I'm looking for a way to Edit a custom Wordpress Admin Page with a page builder, like Divi.

To create custom Admin Pages I used the Plugin 'Custom Admin Page' and it seems like it's not a custom Post type, so the way to enable Divi via custom post types doesn't work.

Is there maybe a way to make the plugin page as a custom post type and then enable Divi through that?

Answer (score 0):

You can read how to use divi to create templates for custom post types in [this](https://wp-types.com/documentation/recommended-themes/toolset-divi-integration/create-templates-for-custom-post-types-with-divi-builder-and-toolset/)